# Update: Unexpected results when using updated 'contains' method. Changes value of foreach 'key'

Tags: javascript, methods

I start with 2 string arrays:

```
var ny_students = [......];
var la_student = [.....];
```

I've got this bit of code that adds to the array:

```
for (i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
if (ny_students.contains(array[i]["Result"])){
    array[i].Class = "Advanced";
}
else{
    if (la_students.contains(array[i]["Result"])){
    array[i].Class = "General";
    }
    else{
    if (i==0) {
    array.splice(i,1);
    }
    else {
        array.splice(i-1,1);
    }
    i--;
    }
 }

}
```

I am getting unexpected results; the 'key' value somehow becomes 'contains'. Here is the 'contains' method definition:

```
Array.prototype.contains = function ( needle ) {
for (i in this) {
   if (this[i] == needle) return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: There is no question asked there.

Comment: Hint: Don't iterate over arrays with `for...in`, or at least make extensions non-enumerable.

Comment: You suggest not using a for loop for arrays...is foreach preferred for this type of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to the Array.prototype the way you have will make the `contains` function enumerable and thus appear in the `for...in` loop

This is why you never use for...in on an array

Alternatively, define `contains` in such a way that is is not enumerable

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'contains', {
    configurable: true,
    value: function ( needle ) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i] == needle) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: the alternative way to define `contains` is still relevant, as some poorly written third party libraries actually use `for...in` on arrays.

Comment: You suggest not using a for loop for arrays...is foreach preferred for this type of thing?

Answer (score 0):

The `for...in` syntax in JS iterates over "iterable" properties of objects, and there is no promise that they'll be returned in order. Sadly enough, the creators of JS didn't think things through and made the "length" property iterable. So we're stuck with using the lame syntax:

```
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) { ... }
```

You don't need your own `contains` method because `arr.indexOf(n)` will return -1 if the value `n` isn't found. So just do `if(arr.indexOf(n) !== -1)` to check if a value is in the array.

Finally, the array has a `concat` method which can combine two arrays (not sure if that will be useful to you in that code, but it's worth pointing out). So if you need to check if a value is in one of two arrays, you could just do :

```
if(arr1.concat(arr2).indexOf(n) != -1) { ... }
```

Note that the elements of arr2 don't get added to arr1 when you do that - it actually returns a new array which contains the elements of both arrays.

Comment: So I should replace 'ny_students.contains(array[i]["Result"])' with 'ny_students.indexOf(array[i]["Result"])' ??

Comment: Almost. Rather with `ny_students.indexOf(array[i]["Result"]) !== -1`. Or actually, you could abuse the fact that 0 evaluates to false and do `ny_students.indexOf(array[i]["Result"])+1`, but that's a bit hacky.

Comment: This sounds like what I want to do because I want to use as little code as possible....but I don't fully understand

Comment: Try to look at [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) of the indexOf method.

Comment: I need to add a newly created key value property ONLY if another key value property matches (ie keys are named differently) Does the concat method do this?

Comment: Ok so I can use indexof(n) but what i need to do is remove the object from the array if it is not found in the other array. This presents other problems